# Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable

Tags: java, android, realm, observable, rx-java2

The function `fetchData` is in a fragment. The `dataRepository` class contains the function that i use to fetch data from the disk:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Log.i("realm", "oncreateView");

    items = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Log.i("realm", "check" + (realm == null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fetchData();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed())
        realm.close();
    Log.i("realm", "ondestroy");
}

    private void fetchData() {

    abcDataRepository = DataRepository.getInstance(realm);

    Observable<List<User>> observable = bcDataRepository.getUser_List();

    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(Users-> {
                Log.i("data", Users.size() + "");

                for (int i = 0; i < Users.size(); i++) {
                    items.add(Users.get(i));
                }
            });
}
```

The DataRepository class:

```
public class DataRepository {

    private Realm realm;

private static PoliticoDataRepository dataRepository = null;

private PoliticoDataRepository(Realm realm) {
    this.realm = realm;
}

public static PoliticoDataRepository getInstance(Realm realm) {
    if (dataRepository == null)
        dataRepository = new PoliticoDataRepository(realm);

    return dataRepository;
}

@Override
public Observable<List<User>> getUser_List() {

    final UserDiskData diskData = new UserDiskData(realm);

    if (diskData.User_Size() > 0) {
        return diskData.getUser_List();
    } else {
        final UserCloudData cloudData = new UserCloudData(realm);
        return cloudData.getUser_List();
    }
}
}
```

The UserDiskData class:

```
class  UserDiskData {

private Realm realm;

UserDiskData(Realm realm) {
    this.realm = realm;
}

int User_Size() {
    final RealmResults<User> results = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
    Log.i("disk", "pulledData" + results.size());
    return results.size();
}

@Override
public Observable<List<User>> getUser_List() {

    Log.i("disk", "called");

    final RealmResults<User> results = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        list.add(results.get(i));

    return Observable.just(list);
}
```

}

The first time the app runs fine but when i exit the app and open it again, it crashes and gives an error saying `This Realm instance has already been closed`, making it unusable.
It works perfectly fine if i skip out the `realm.close` at the end. Should i manually close the realm object, if so how?
For some reason `realm==null` returns true when i close the app and open it again, why does it do that, especially considering `realm.getdefaultinstance` is being called right before it.

Comment: move `close()` to `onDestroyView()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that didnt work, the oncreateView gets called each time the app opens so realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); gets executed but realm still remains null for some reason.

Comment: Answer seems to be here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4149#issuecomment-277949679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague @zaki50 points out:

`DataRepository` keeps a **static** reference to `PoliticoDataRepository`.  That means that `DataRepository.getInstance(Realm realm)` can return an old instance of `PoliticoDataRepository` which contains the closed Realm instance.

You must remove static field and make sure that `DataRepository.getInstance(Realm realm)` always returns an instance that refers to the passed Realm instance.